# Equivalent of Presto REPLACE function in Hive

Tags: hive, presto, trino

I have a condition currently in presto like below

`replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(UPPER(FIELDNAME),' ',''),'LLC',''),'INC',''),'INTERNATIONAL',''),'LTD',''),'.',''),',',''),'QMT','')`

What will be the equivalent function in Hive that will serve the exact same prurpose? Will regexp_replace work for the above scenario?

Used regexp_replace in the above condition instead of replace, but it is throwing me the below error.

`FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 1:255 Wrong arguments ''('': No matching method for class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFRegExpReplace with (string, string). Possible choices: _FUNC_(string, string, string) (state=42000,code=10014)`

It would be greatful if someone can help on this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is true. regexp_replace is the command that you can use. You can give the list of substrings to be substituted as a list separated by '|' and you need to use '\' to give any special characters which might act as wildcards like - .  or ? or * etc. Below is the sample usage.

```
SELECT regexp_replace(upper(fieldname),'LTD|QMT|INTERNATIONAL|ORG|INC|\\.|,| ','') from my_table;
```

Comment: the above one works fine for the mentioned req, but there is a different condition like below, ```replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(upper(pod.fieldname),' ',''),'.',''),')',''),'('),',',''),'-',''),'/',''),'&',''),'_',''),'''','')``` . This throws an error around the '''','' . error shown in original post. Any workaround?

Comment: In your replace functions, you have forgotten to use the string to replace '('. Use below:
replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
upper(pod.fieldname),' ',''),'.',''),')',''),'(',''),',',''),'-',''),'/',''),'&',''),'_',''),'''','')

Comment: I actually used regexp_replace for this too and it works. The only downside is . doesn't work when i try to parse it in a yaml. so i have to use translate(regexp_replace(fieldname), |,|-|_|,''),'.','')